# p5js- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eats' of undefined (sketch: line 76)

Tags: debugging, p5.js

Can someone please help me with what I'm doing wrong here. I'm completely new to programming, and am currently learning p5js at university. I'm trying to create 'cells' floating around in space, and when they hit each other they combine together. It works for a minute but then I get an error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eats' of undefined (sketch: line 76)"

This is my code:

```
function Cell(x, y, r) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;
  this.speedx = random(-1, 1);
  this.speedy = random(-1, 1);
  this.width2 = 0.5;
  this.col = color(255);

  this.show = function() {
    fill(this.col);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
  }

  this.move = function() {
    this.x = this.x + this.speedx;
    this.y = this.y + this.speedy;
  }

  this.bounce = function() {
    if (this.x > width || this.x < 0) {
      this.speedx = -this.speedx;
    }
    if (this.y > height || this.y < 0) {
      this.speedy = -this.speedy;
    }
  }

  // this.changeColor = function (){
  //this.col = color(random(255), random (255), random(255));
  //}

  this.eats = function(other) {
    var d = dist(this.x, this.y, other.x, other.y);
    if (d < this.r + other.r) {
      var sum = PI * this.r * this.r + PI * other.r * other.r;
      this.r = sqrt(sum / PI);
      //this.r += other.r;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // this.intersects = function(other){
  // var d= dist(this.x, this.y, other.x, other.y);
  //if (d < this.r + other.r) {
  //var sum = PI * this.r * this.r + PI * other.r * other.r;
  //this.r = sqrt(sum / PI);
  //this.r += other.r;
  //return true;
  //} else {
  //return false;
  //}
  //}

}

var cells = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    cells[i] = new Cell(random(width), random(height), 10);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (var i = cells.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    cells[i].show();
    cells[i].move();
    cells[i].bounce();

    for (var j = cells.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (j != i && cells[i].eats(cells[j])) {
        //  cells[i].changeColor();
        // cells[j].changeColor();
        cells.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing cells from cells array using `cells.splice(j, 1);`. So when it checks for that on next loop, its throwing error.

Comment: Is there a simple way to avoid this from happening? I want to remove the cells from the array when they intersect, but I want it to stop doing this at the point when there's only 1 cell left on the screen

Comment: check like `if (j != i && cells[i] && cells[i].eats(cells[j])) {`

Comment: Done! Thanks again :)